# Converting String Data Value into date

Tags: mysql, string, date, format

Good Morning All;

I currently have a MySQL table where there are 3 date fields (Columns) that were loaded as strings in this format 20140101 YYYYmmdd. I would like to convert this to a date format 2014/01/01 YYYY/mm/dd. Can someone please provide a simple sql syntax that would alter the table to a date format from a string and change the column to display the dates like this 2014/01/01 and not like 20140101. Thanks to all

Comment: MySQL provides a datatype `DATE` specifically designed to store and manipulate "date" values. There's no "format" for DATE columns per se, but MySQL uses a default format `YYYY-mm-dd` for date string literals, and when converting `DATE` to/from `VARCHAR`. MySQL provides functions `FORMAT_DATE` and `STR_TO_DATE` to convert between `DATE` and `VARCHAR`, and you can use string values in lots of formats, just provide appropriate format specifier e.g. `'%Y/%m/%d'`. Did you want to keep the column `VARCHAR` and just change the contents of the column, or did you want to convert the column to `DATE`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
date_format(str_to_date(datecolumn, '%Y%m%d'),'%Y/%m/%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to reformat the values in the `VARCHAR` column, assuming that the column with sufficient length e.g. `VARCHAR(10)`, and all the values are eight characters in length...

You could do something like this:

```
UPDATE mytable t
   SET t.mycol = CONCAT( LEFT( t.mycol ,4)
                       , '/'
                       , SUBSTR( t.mycol ,5,2)
                       ,'/'
                       , SUBSTR( t.mycol ,7,2)
                      ) 
 WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(t.mycol) = 8
```

We want something in the statement that will prevent the statement from "working" a second time, if it's inadvertently re-run. It doesn't have to be `CHAR_LENGTH`. We might want to include a check that the value doesn't already contain a slash character `AND t.mycol NOT LIKE '%/%'`.

---

But *why on earth* are "date" values being stored in character columns, rather than in `DATE` datatype, which is custom designed for storing and working with date values?

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycol DATE ... ;
```

(If the column is defined as `NOT NULL`, has a default value, has a comment, those attributes can be retained, they need to be included in the new column specification, e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable MODIFY mycol DATE NOT NULL COMMENT 'creation date';
```

Note that `DATE` columns do not have a "format" per se. When converting to string, MySQL uses date format `'%Y-%m-%d'`. And MySQL expects string literals representing date values to be in that same format. To get a value from a `DATE` column converted to string in format `'yyyy/mm/dd'`.

```
  SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date_col,'%Y/%m/%d') AS date_col
```

To get a string value in that format converted to DATE datatype

```
 SELECT STR_TO_DATE('2015/06/01','%Y/%m/%d')
```